# Enabling submit button when all inputs are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've checked for mostly all answers to similar questions. I can't get it to work.

Is it because I use jquery library provided by Google?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Hello, world!</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            $('form > input').keyup(function(){
                var empty = false;
                $('form > input').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).val() == ''){
                        empty = true;
                    } 
                });
                if (empty){
                    $('#submitForm').prop('disabled','disabled');
                } else {
                    $('#submitForm').prop('disabled',false);
                }
            });
        })()
    </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
    <form method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitForm" name="Log In" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: Because your submit button is input as well and that value is not asigned. change it to button

Comment: `keyup` won't catch everything, I can right click `copy` or `paste` without using a keyboard.

Comment: Why is this simplest question upvoted? I added working answer below..

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea...
Let's use change event like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Hello, world!</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          empty = true;
          $("form input").change(function(){
            $("form input").each(function(){
              if ($(this).val().trim() == ''){
                empty = true;
                return false;
              }
              empty = false;
            })
            if (!empty){
              $("#submitForm").removeAttr('disabled')
            }
            else{
              $("#submitForm").attr('disabled','disabled')
            }
          })
        })
    </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
    <form method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="submitForm" name="Log In" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Checkout [**This DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/nuliwisudu/edit?html,output)

Also, the most easier solution that does not need JavaScript is using HTML attribute `required`

```
<form method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" required><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" required> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="submitForm" name="Log In">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Hello, world!</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form > input').on('change, keyup', function(){
                var empty = false;
                $('form > input').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).val() == ''){
                        empty = true;
                    } 
                });
                if (!empty){
                    $('#submitForm').removeAttr('disabled');
                }else{
                    $('#submitForm').attr('disabled','');
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
    <form method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <button id="submitForm" name="Log In" disabled> Submit </button>
    </form>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

I changed your code since it was not working....

And as Erik mentioned if someone copy/paste keyup wont work so I added change as well.

Comment: `on('change, keyup'` should not have a comma in there.  Event types are separated by space, not comma like selectors.  The comma makes the change event not be captured so pasting a value by mouse only is not registered.

Comment: it is by my mouse

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with pure JavaScript

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=submit])');
const submit = document.querySelector('[type=submit]');

function areInputsEmpty() {
return Array.from(inputs).every(input => input.value !== '');
}

function toggleDisable(event) {
    const values = areInputsEmpty();

    if (values) {
        submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        submit.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('keyup', toggleDisable));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        label { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```